# Angular resource custom URL is using query strings and POST parameters

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api, rest, put

I've written a custom method on an Angular resource in my application for activating a user. The API endpoint is `/users/activate` and an activation code must be PUTed to this endpoint. This is what my resource looks like:

```
app.factory('User', ['$resource',
    function($resource){
        return $resource('http://api.site.dev/users/:id', {id: '@id'}, {
            activate: {method:'PUT', params:{code: '@code'}, url: 'http://api.site.dev/users/activate'}
        });
    }]);
```

and I'm using it in my controller like so:

```
User.activate({code: $routeParams.code});
```

As you can see from the network log on Chrome, the activation code is being sent in the query string and request body:

[image]

How can I change the resource to just pass the activation code in the request body and not in the query string?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just remove `params` from the action declaration:

```
activate: {method:'PUT', url: 'http://api.site.dev/users/activate'}
```

Comment: could you please let me know the route cause for that?