# POST request to API sending parameteres in URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, cordova

I've a web in Ruby on Rails, which works. Now, I'm developing a mobile app to complement that web. I'm using Cordova and AngularJS (v1.2.13).

The first step to use the app (as a user) is to sign in using the same credentials as in the web. In order to connect the app with the database I'm developing an API in Rails.

Signing in from the app works, but when making the POST call to the API, the parameters are attached to the URL:

```
http://localhost:3000/api/sign_in?email=user@example.com&password=1234
```

This is not safe, for obvious reasons. I want those parameters removed from the URL:

```
http://localhost:3000/api/sign_in
```

I don't understand why the parameters are not being passed *'hidden'*. What am I missing?

In my angular service I have:

```
app.factory('loginService', ['$resource', 'BASE_URL', function($resource, BASE_URL){
    return $resource(BASE_URL + '/api/sign_in', {email:'@email', password:'@password'}, {
        'sign_in': {
            method: 'POST',
            isArray: false,
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        }
    });
}]);
```

And in the controller:

```
var logged = loginService.sign_in({email: $scope.email, password: $scope.password},
                 function(data){ /*do whatever with the data*/}
             );
```

**EDIT**

I forgot to mention that I use Devise for authentication.
Routing:

```
namespace :api do 
    devise_scope :user do 
      post "/sign_in", :to => 'sessions#create'
    end
  end
```

which gives me:

```
api_sign_in POST   /api/sign_in(.:format)
```

The controller, in case it's needed:

```
class Api::SessionsController < Api::ApiController

  include Devise::Controllers::InternalHelpers

  def create
    ...
  end

end
```

Comment: What type of routing are you using?

Comment: @Pytth I added the routing in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to do it thanks to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23528512/1799880)

It basically sais to remove the params from the service:

```
maappServices.factory('loginService', ['$resource', '$http', 'BASE_URL', function($resource, $http, BASE_URL){
    return $resource(BASE_URL + '/api/sign_in', {/*REMOVE params from this part*/}, {
        'sign_in': {
            method: 'POST',
            isArray: false
        }
    });
}]);
```

And now the call to the api is done like this: `Started POST "/api/sign_in"`
I also **removed the header part** in order to work.

Answer (score 0):

I am not all too familiar with Ruby (that is Ruby, right?), but if you simply want to hit an API endpoint without changing the URL, here is an example of some code that has been working for me without the issues you have described. I think the big thing here is the `/:id/:controller` part.

I hope this helps, but I am using client-side routing so idk how that would affect things.

```
 angular.module('dayakoApp')
  .factory('User', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/users/:id/:controller', {
      id: '@_id'
    },
    {
      changePassword: {
        method: 'PUT',
        params: {
          controller:'password'
        }
      },
      get: {
        method: 'GET',
        params: {
          id:'me'
        }
      }
      });
  });
```

Comment: I finally found a solution. I posted it. Thanks!